# Why do I get AttributeError for one method but not other?

Tags: python

I have 2 variables that are suppose to do the same thing but I cannot figure out why the second one throws me a **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'** error but the first works fine. Can anyone explain why the second doesn't work?

```
def camel_case(string):
     n = string.title()
     return n.replace(" ", "")
camel_case(" camel case word")
```

```
def camel_case(string):
     return string.title().string.replace(" ", "")
camel_case(" camel case word")
```

Comment: Because in the first function you are not trying to access a non-existent attribute named `string`. By the way, these functions are not methods (because they are not written in a class)

Comment: You call the `replace` method using the return value of `string.title()`, not the original argument `string` (which, of course, is not an attribute of anything, but rather a local variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just you don't need 'string':

```
return string.title().replace(" ", "")
```